# Getting context name when using Labels for alternative subrules

Tags: antlr4

ANTLR Version: 4.11.1

Grammar: cpp/CPP14Parser.g4 in https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/

ANTLR Target Language: C++

I modified the selectionStatement rule
From

```
    If LeftParen condition RightParen statement (Else statement)?
    | Switch LeftParen condition RightParen statement;
```

To

```
    If LeftParen condition RightParen statement (Else statement)?   # ifStatement
    | Switch LeftParen condition RightParen statement   # switchStatement
    ;
```

Just added labels to the alternatives.

In my ParserListener, using enterEveryRule and exitEveryRule, I create a list of entered and exited context names. The sytnax used to find context name is

```
parser.getRuleNames()[context->getRuleIndex()]
```

From the above list, in exitIfStatement function, I am unable to locate "ifStatement", but only "selectionStatement". What change do I need to the find-context-name syntax to get "ifStatement"?

Comment: There isn't any rule name generated for alt labels. You can see this if you use the Parser.TraceListener. You can also see that there is no '"ifStatement"' nor '"switchStatement"' rule name string value in the generated code, only node classes with the alt names. The runtime doesn't create one either from parse tree node types. The pattern on using alt labels is to define the enter/exit methods that are named after the alt labels, not enter/exitEveryRule. But if you insist, you could perform a test in enter/exitEveryRule using reflection on the type of the parse tree node.

Comment: Thanks, if you could please add this as an answer, I will accept it as solution.